# how to stop writing the android logcat into file in dos prompt

Tags: eclipse, dos, adb, android-logcat, android-2.2-froyo

I'm developing an android application using eclipse using **sdk version 2.2 api level 8.** in Windows XP.
  
In eclipse, the logcat has some buffer limit. If the logcat data is goes beyond the limit then it is truncated. Then it shows only last part. So if the logcat data is large means it is helpless.

So I'm trying to write the logcat in  a file by using the following command in the dos prompt.

```
  adb logcat >D:\log.txt
```

Its working but I'm not able to terminate the writing into file.

How to stop writing the logcat into file in DOS prompt?

Comment: There is an option in logcat to save your log data,You just need to select and click on export button,your selected data will be save in  text file..

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your problem

1) Removing size restriction on the console output(theoretically unlimited size)

> **Go to Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console
>     Uncheck "Limit Console Output" (Alternatively you can increase the Console buffer size)**

2) To stop writing to file, hit **ctrl + c** in DOS prompt. Infact ctrl + c stops any      executing command in DOS prompt.